# Javascript Object manipulation to create an Object list with a variable id

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am not comfortable with certain subtleties, and here are 2 days that I go around in circles, to carry out "manipulations" of Objects in javascript (NodeJS), I therefore appeal to your knowledge!

I send elements from a json as a parameter in a .js script.
in this script, I would like to process the elements sent as a parameter (by a loop), to add them to a list, then to be able to add others "manually", to finally get a "list" of the set with different additional information.

my "test" script where I simulate the parameters received and "try" to get this "list":

```
let params = JSON.parse('{ "100": 3, "101": 1 }')  // simulate parameters
let lstObj = {} // content all the list obj

// only for the test
function foo(type) {
    return "type is " + type;
}
function addToList(id, type) {
    let obj = {
        id: id,
        type: type,
        test: foo(type)
    }
    console.log('from addToList() -> ', obj);
    return obj;
}

// process the Obj from parameters
let index = 0;
for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(params)) {
    console.log("from Param: ", `${key} -> ${value}`, " or ", key, "->", value);

    obj = addToList(key, value);   // seem work

    //lstObj.key = obj;    // use 'key' not the key value
    //lstObj.[key] = obj;  // error
    //lstObj.`${key}` = obj; // error
    //lstObj.["999"] = obj;  // error
    //index++;  lstObj.index = obj;  // bad :)
    lstObj.a999 = obj;  // Work ! but how can a make it ?
}
console.log('\nResult -> ', lstObj);

// Now want to manualy add other Obj in the List, like this ?
// lstObj.999 = addToList("999", 3)
```

I would like to get a result  like this:

```
{
    "100": {id: 100, type: 1, test: 'Type is 1', ....}
    "102": {id: 102, type: 3, test: 'Type is 3', ....}
    "110": {id: 110, type: 1, test: 'Type is 1', ....}
    "305": {id: 305, type: 2, test: 'Type is 2', ....}
}
```

The purpose of being able to subsequently retrieve the object of an element by a call like: "lstobj.101"

Thank's a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to assign the key to the object.
Change this line

```
lstObj.a999 = obj;  // Work ! but how can a make it ?
```

to

```
lstObj[key] = obj;
```

What this does is assign whatever value is contained by variable `key` to be a key in variable `lstObj`, then assign the value of `obj` as it's value.
For example

```
let key = 'exampleKey';
let value = 'exampleValue';
let obj = {};
obj[key]=value; //now object is { 'exampleKey': 'exampleValue' }
```

Comment: Thanks to your example, I understood where my concern was, with "obstinacy" I wanted to stick a "."
lstObj.[key] = obj; // error

But now things are immediately better: D in my loop with:  lstObj[key] = obj;